# How can the process of hyperbola problems achieve the desired results?

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

As shown in the picture above, in the hyperbola x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2==1, point P is any point on the hyperbola, through the point P respectively do two asymptotes of the hyperbola parallel line PA, PB. The intersection point of the asymptotes are A and B. Prove that the area of quadrilateral OAPB is a fixed value.

My personal attempt is as follows: But the result of the intermediate process and the final result is not what I want, how to deal with?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
lines1 = y == b/a x; lines2 = y == -b/a x; p = {x0, y0}; line1 = 
 y - y0 == b/a (x - x0); line2 = y - y0 == -b/a (x - x0); o = {0, 0};
{xA, yA} = First@SolveValues[{lines2, line1}, {x, y}] // Simplify
{xB, yB} = First@SolveValues[{lines1, line2}, {x, y}] // Simplify
OP = Simplify[Norm[o - p], {x0, y0} \[Element] Reals]
lineop = y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{o, p}, x] == 0 // Simplify
pt = {xB, yB};
pol = Apply[Subtract, lineop];
A1 = Coefficient[pol, x];
B1 = Coefficient[pol, y];
distance = 
 Simplify[
  Abs[pol /. Thread[{x, y} -> pt]]/Sqrt[A1^2 + B1^2], {a, b} > 
   0 And[{x0, y0} \[Element] Reals, x0^2/a^2 - y0^2/b^2 == 1]]
Simplify[distance, x0^2/a^2 - y0^2/b^2 == 1]
s = Simplify[OP distance, x0^2/a^2 - y0^2/b^2 == 1]
```

The distance variable from the middle point B to line OP Should Be:

```
distance = (a b)/(2 Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2])
```

The final result of area determination should be:

```
s=a b/2
```

Since point P is on the hyperbola, then:

```
x0^2/a^2 - y0^2/b^2 == 1
```

The equation can be converted to:

```
b^2 x0^2 - a^2 y0^2 == a^2 b^2
```

Substitute the above expression into the result generated by the software to get the final desired result. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution presented in the style of an interactive algebraic calculation, using variable names that should make it self-documenting, and using postfix ordering that should make the sequence of computations clearer.

Initialise the hyperbola and its asymptotes.

```
eqn = x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1
solnsHyp = Solve[eqn, y]
yHyps[x_] = y /. solnsHyp
eqn2 = eqn // Factor
solnsAsymp = eqn2[[1]] // Numerator // Solve[# == 0, y] &
yAsymps[x_] = y /. solnsAsymp
slopes = yAsymps[x] // D[#, x] &

(*
x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1

{{y -> -(Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + b^2 x^2]/a)}, {y -> Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + b^2 x^2]/
   a}}

{-(Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + b^2 x^2]/a), Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + b^2 x^2]/a}

-(((-b x + a y) (b x + a y))/(a^2 b^2)) == 1

{{y -> -((b x)/a)}, {y -> (b x)/a}}

{-((b x)/a), (b x)/a}

{-(b/a), b/a}
*)
```

Compute the 4 vertices of the polygon.

```
pntO = {0, 0}
pntP = {x, yHyps[x][[2]]}
pntA = {px, py} /. 
   Solve[{{px, py} == pntO + u {1, slopes[[1]]}, {px, py} == 
       pntP + v {1, slopes[[2]]}}, {u, v, px, py}][[1]] // Simplify
pntB = {px, py} /. 
   Solve[{{px, py} == pntP + u {1, slopes[[1]]}, {px, py} == 
       pntO + v {1, slopes[[2]]}}, {u, v, px, py}][[1]] // Simplify

(*
{0, 0}

{x, Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + b^2 x^2]/a}

{(b x - Sqrt[b^2 (-a^2 + x^2)])/(
 2 b), (-b x + Sqrt[b^2 (-a^2 + x^2)])/(2 a)}

{(b x + Sqrt[b^2 (-a^2 + x^2)])/(2 b), (
 b x + Sqrt[b^2 (-a^2 + x^2)])/(2 a)}
*)
```

Compute the area of the polygon.

```
Area[Polygon[{pntO, pntA, pntP, pntB}]]

(*
1/2 Abs[a b]
*)
```